# CSS definitions separated in page

Tags: html, css, dhtml

People use a wysiwyg to create a message.

I do not have any control over the string produced at this stage. I simply 'get' the string including all formatting through a web service, which returns a single string.

So for example I will get back:

```
<p>here is the <a href='http://www.example.com'>link</a>
```

Unfortunately I also get back font definitions and other styled attributes in the same string. For example

```
<!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Corbel;
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 2 4 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
```

obviously this then changes the formatting of the entire page, rather than just the message created using the wysiwyg since it defines HTML tags rather than using an actual class or id.

Is it possible to somehow separate the page so that any CSS definition inside that only applies to that HTML block?
Or am I going to have to put it into a div block with an ID and somehow go through the returned string (that contains the style elements) and update any definition to be a child of that ID? i.e. Instead of `a:visited` I would need to render it as `#exampleID a:visited`

If I would need to do the latter, anyone have any ideas on the best way to go about this?

Thanks all. This is only my second question and still learning the correct way to post these questions. So please ask any information you feel I have missed and will update the post.

Comment: what wysiwyg  are you using? how are you accessing it's content?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using the wysiwyg - I can only access the string after the fact, through a web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow separate the page so that any CSS definition inside that only applies to that HTML block?

Render it in an `iframe`. As unfortunately the [proper alternative has no support whatsoever in current browsers](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/#support).

Comment: Yea I thought about this also, but unfortunately not really what I am looking for. Would prefer to keep it in same page if possible as it has other functionality and styling in it which will cause a nightmare if using an iframe.

Comment: Since scoped styles do not work the only alternative is to parse the CSS and insert some kind of `#id` prefix to every rule. I'd just use the iframe.

Comment: That is PERFECT and exactly what I am looking for. So unfortunate there is no support in current browsers.

Comment: Yep, would be perfect hehe. To my surprise it [is supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style), but the Webkit implementation was experimental since v20, and removed in v35 eventually. There is no planned implementation in Webkit and IE/Edge to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, there is a jQuery plugin the link you have given has recommended. I am going to see how they have done it and modify it to my needs. If all else fails, will go with the iframe. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah the plugin may help. It's very hard to do it yourself, as intelligently parsing CSS is far less trivial than it sounds, if you want to properly handle cases like `content:"table { width:100% }"` and `/* a {color:blue} */`.

Answer (score -1):

## Way 1

Use an `iframe` to show the contents.

It's not a good way if there are a lot of such blocks.

## Way 2

Add some `id` to the container and update css selectors from so that they have this id as the first element. I think, it's the best way.

## Do NOT use way 3

Attribute `scoped` has been removed from specification and has a poor browser support.

## Warning

Anyway, you have to validate the code somehow to prevent malware scripts inside of it.